# Asymptotic Radial Wave Equation

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to reproduce the following solution to the ODE, 
$$\frac{d^{2}u}{d\rho^{2}} = \frac{l*(l+1)}{\rho^{2}}u$$

Solution: $$u\left(\rho\right) = C\rho^{l+1}+D\rho^{-l}$$

What I've tried in Mathematica using `DSolve` is

```
DSolve[u''[ρ] == (l*(l + 1))/ρ^2*u[ρ], u[ρ], ρ]
```

However, when I try using `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` on my *Mathematica* output, I can't get it into the simple version as above.

The *Mathematica* Output Solution that I get from the use of `DSolve` is

```
{{u[ρ] -> ρ^(1/2 I Sqrt[l] Sqrt[1 + l] (-(I/(Sqrt[l] Sqrt[1 + l])) - Sqrt[-4 - 1/(l (1 + l))]))C[1]
    + ρ^(1/2 I Sqrt[l] Sqrt[1 + l] (-(I/(Sqrt[l] Sqrt[1 + l])) + Sqrt[-4 - 1/(l (1 + l))]))C[2]}}
```

Thanks very much for your valuable time.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to add the assumption that $l,\rho\ge 0$:

```
Assuming[{l >= 0, ρ >= 0}, 
 Simplify[DSolve[u''[ρ] == (l*(l + 1))/ρ^2*u[ρ], 
   u[ρ], ρ]]]

(* ==> {{u[ρ] -> ρ^(1 + l) C[1] + ρ^-l C[2]}} *)
```